# Twitter Bootstrap Responsive Background Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, single-page-application

I'm trying to make a site similar to this: http://www.awerest.com/demo/myway/light/

A single paged site with a responsive image that takes up the full screen, on any device. That's my issue I can't figure out a way to get a background image to go full screen on any device.

```
<img src="C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\City-Skyline.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

I came across this but no luck, if some one can point me into the right direction on how to do this it would be very appertained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crucial part here is to set up the height of your content as 100% *relative* to the viewport (`html` element). By applying the background image to a `div` and not just using an `img` you also have a lot more flexibility in how its displayed, `background-position` keeps it always centered, `background-size:cover` keeps it scaled.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ55H/)

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div>More Content</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div:first-of-type {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSbcnkIVXLz23PALu8JD-cTGe8KbXKC1JV0gBM_x1lx3JyaNqE7);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
}
div:last-of-type {
    background:green;
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    height:100%;
}
```